# Sybase Python ODBC

Tags: python, odbc, sybase

I am unable to capture print statements on the console when using with Sybase Python with ODBC connectivity. I have a procedure which have few print statements and on execution from unix promot or sybase unix SQL prompt, I can see the messages on screen/console. However when execute from python using python ODBC connectivity, not getting the print statement outputs.

I am setting the connectivity with ODBC and creating a cursor. With cursor I am executing the sybase procedure. 
ex: cursor.execute(procedure)
to get the result I am using cursor.fetchall() but nothing is returning from it. I tried to use a out parameter as well but no output still.

My need to capture the print messages on console which executing sybase procedure in python with ODBC connectivity

Comment: Print statements are not classed as query output statements but rather system messages or warnings. You could change these to select statements instead of print statements or alternatively use the info in https://answers.sap.com/questions/11708765/using-python-to-catch-server-messages.html

Comment: I add select in place of print but no luck

Comment: Try using direct rather than a cursor maybe?

Comment: Please detail how to using direct rather than a cursor

Comment: Have you checked the manual - theres a separate call for procs (callproc) rather than execute http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc20155.1570/html/OS_SDK_nf/OS_SDK_nf101.htm